# how to increase the label size according to text in static table view in swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have 3 custom cells in Static TableView. All cells have different heights. But I need to make height of newsDetail label dynamic according to its content size. It was easy to make dynamic for dynamic tableview by setting rowHeight and estimatedRowHeight. But it didn't work out for Static TableView. I searched but couldn't find solution for this, anyone please could help me in swift 3?

Comment: are you useing autolayout ?

Comment: Yes..I have used auto layout through storyboard!! @@ balkaran singh

Comment: can you show the lable constraint  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Autolayout` you need to use,

**In `viewDidLoad()` provide estimated height**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0 //you can provide any
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

**Implement Delegate method**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

**Need to provide `constraint` on your label in `UITableViewCell`.**

`Top`, `Bottom`, `Trailing`, `Leading` and *no need to provide* any fix `height` constraint. 
And make `numberOfLines` to `0` of `UILabel`